# is there a way to write a switch statement inside a for loop in C programming

Tags: c

Im trying to write a switch state ment inside a for loop and im getting errors

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
   static int i=0
    
    for (i=0; i<16; i++){
        switch(i){
            case 0: printf("ZERO");
            break;
            case 1: printf("ONE");
            break;
            case 2: printf("TWO");
            break;
            default:
            printf("MORE THAN 2");
            break;
        }
        
    }      
}
```

the error id found below

```
expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘for’
     for (i=0; i<16; i++){
     ^~~

error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
     for (i=0; i<16; i++){
                        ^
 error: expected statement before ‘)’ token
```

Comment: `switch (i) ...` not `a`. Voted to close as typo

Comment: Please do not post code as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question. And please give the exact errors.

Comment: i replaced the i with a and the code is still not running. is there something wring with the structure?

Comment: `static int i=0` -> `static int i=0;`

Comment: OT: There's really no reason to make `i` a `static` variable in the program as shown.

Comment: `expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘for’`: what is not clear about this error message?

Answer (score 1):

You omitted the semicolon after the variable declaration.

`static int i=0;` is correct.

Try the following code. Everything works fine.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
   static int i=0;
    
    for (i=0; i<16; i++){
        switch(i){
            case 0: printf("ZERO");
            break;
            case 1: printf("ONE");
            break;
            case 2: printf("TWO");
            break;
            default:
            printf("MORE THAN 2");
            break;
        }
        
    }      
}
```

Comment: if he solved your problem please mark his answer as accepted.